# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str':- return sum(numbers) / float(len(numbers))

Tags: python, python-3.x

below is my code and it is giving me error like this 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

```
def mean(numbers):
  return sum(numbers) / float(len(numbers))
def stdev(numbers):
  avg = mean(numbers)
  variance = sum([pow(x - avg, 2) for x in numbers]) / float(len(numbers) - 1)
return math.sqrt(variance)
```

i tried changing it like this

```
 def mean(numbers):
  return sum([int(numbers)]) / float(len(numbers))
def stdev(numbers):
  avg = mean(numbers)
  variance = sum([pow(x - avg, 2) for x in numbers]) / float(len(numbers) - 1)
return math.sqrt(variance)
```

but this time it is giving me this error 
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

Comment: Please provide your imports, and an example of how you call your functions, else it is impossible to reproduce your problem. I try with `l = [1,2,3,4]` `print mean(l), stddev(l)` and it works fine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: If numbers is actually a list of strings representing integers, then obviously you can't use numeric operations on them.  Convert it to a list of integers with map(int, numbers). But really that should be the responsibility of the caller, and NOT done inside a function which expects an iterable of actual numeric data.

Answer (score 0):

change your first function to something like

```
def mean(numbers):
  return sum([int(x) for x in numbers]) / float(len(numbers))
```

Comment: As I was just saying in the main thread, I don't think this is appropriate inside the function. You're changing the actual value returned by correct use of the function in order to customize bad data from one particular use case. Better to fix the input before calling the function.

Comment: that's very true.
what I wanted to do was give him a way to implement his chosen logic, though I agree it's better to cast the data into its final form before sending it off to be worked on.